# in aggregate $neogear "distanceField " is in meters or in another unit?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the aggregate $geoNear and I don't know if the field distanceField return a value in meters or in another unit

```
{near : { type: "Point", coordinates: [long,lat] },
 distanceField: "dist.calculated",
 maxDistance: 50000, 
includeLocs:"dist.location", 
num: 10, spherical :true }
```

I only want to know the unit of measurement
Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/):

> Specify the distance in meters if the specified point is GeoJSON and in radians if the specified point is legacy coordinate pairs.

So it's in meters in your case since you're specifying a [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geojson-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your help